# kibana 6.0.1 stopped working after installing node.js and npm?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, lodash, kibana

I am running Kibana 6.0.1 and everything was working fine until I have installed Node.js (version 8.9.3) and npm (5.6.0) on (im running Windows 10). the error im getting is:

```
module.js:471
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'lodash/internal/toPath'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\angel\kibana-6\src\utils\unset.js:12:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\angel\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

I have no idea what happened. I tried to install lodash but that gave me errors as well.

Comment: Please mention the Node.js and npm versions you’re using in the question

Comment: sorry I shouldve mentioned it, updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Kibana 6.0 uses node version 6.11.5 ( Refer https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/6.0/.node-version)

Please try installing this node version and try running kibana again.

`// Install node version 6.11.5
nvm install 6.11.5
// Use node version 6.11.5
nvm use 6.11.5`

Did you do install the correct version of lodash for this kibana 6.0 as suggested here: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/6.0/package.json?